# Deduce type from `static constexpr` to `using`

Tags: c++, constexpr

is it possible to "deduce" the type of a `static constexpr` to a `using`?

https://compiler-explorer.com/z/hKzqhv7Pa

```
#include <chrono>

// Bar.h
using Bar = std::chrono::milliseconds;               
static constexpr std::chrono::milliseconds BAR{100};

// Foo.h
struct Foo {
  // Is there a way to get ride of the `using Bar` 
  // and "deduce" the type of `BAR` in a  (elegant) 
  // way to the `using Type`?
  using Type = Bar // decltype(BAR); // does not compile
  static constexpr auto FOO = BAR;
};

int main() {
  Foo::Type x{0};
  x = Foo::FOO; // candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'Foo::Type' (aka 'const duration<long, ratio<1, 1000> >'), but method is not marked const
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Zlatan

Comment: In the future, please attach error messages for the code you post. Don't just say "doesn't work".

Comment: Sorry, I will do (I tough adding the compiler explorer link is sufficient enough).

Comment: Links can stop working or their contents change. Please make questions *self contained*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decltype(BAR)` does work. It just returnrs a const type, so the assignment in `main` fails. Use `std::remove_const_t<decltype(BAR)>`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :)